# Applying transitions selectively to react router routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-transition-group

I have a group of Routes as children of a TransitionGroup and would like to apply the transition to only some route changes. My code is as follows:

```
<TransitionGroup>
    <CSSTransition timeout={300} classNames='fade' key={location.key}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<HomeScreen />} />
        <Route path='/menu'>
          <Route path=':category' element={<MenuScreen />} />
          <Route path='' element={<MenuScreen />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </CSSTransition>
  </TransitionGroup>
```

I want the transition when moving from the HomeScreen component to the MenuScreen component and vice versa, but not when switching between MenuScreen routes. For example, if the user moves from '/menu/appetizers' to '/menu/desserts', I do not want the transition to trigger. As it is, the transition works fine, but triggers every time I navigate to a new route. I assume there is a simple way to do this, but I am relatively new to React and can't seem to find any examples.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, but it's a bit hack-y and inelegant.

I simply got the first component of the current path as follows:

```
  const location = useLocation();
  
  var pathName = location.pathname;

  const components = pathName.split('/');

  if (components.length > 1) {
    pathName = components[1];
  }
```

...and then used that as the key for the CSSTransition:

```
<CSSTransition timeout={300} classNames='fade' key={pathName}>
```

If anyone knows of a better solution, please do share.